# Scala manipulate json object

Tags: json, scala, azure-data-factory

I have a dynamic json object generated with a certain format and I would like to manipulate that object to map it to another format in scala.
The problem is that the names of the fields are dynamic so "field1" and "field2" can be anything.
Is there any way to do it dynamically in scala?

The original object:

```
{
 "field1": {
  "value" "some value 1",
  "description": "some test description",
  ... 
 },
 "field2": {
  "value" "some value 2",
  "description": "some test description",
  ... 
 }
}
```

And I'd like to convert it to something like:

```
{
 "field1": "some value 1",
 "field2": "some value 2"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can collect all `keys` and then check if the `downField("value")` exists

```
import io.circe._
import io.circe.literal.JsonStringContext

object CirceFieldsToMap {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val json: Json =
      json"""{
             "field1": {
                "foo" : "bar1",
                "value" : "foobar1"
             },
             "field2": {
                "foo" : "bar2",
                "value" : "foobar2"
             },
             "field3": {
                "foo" : "bar2"
             }
             }"""

    implicit val decodeFoo = new Decoder[Map[String, Option[String]]] {
      final def apply(c: HCursor): Decoder.Result[Map[String, Option[String]]] = {
        val result = c.keys.get //// You should handle the .get properly ( if None it breaks)
                            .toList
                            .foldLeft(List.empty[(String, Option[String])]) { case (acc, key) =>
          acc :+ (key, c.downField(key).downField("value").as[String].toOption)
        }
        Right(result.toMap)
      }
    }

    val myField01 = json.as[Map[String, Option[String]]]
    println(myField01)   //Right(Map(field1 -> Some(foobar1), field2 -> Some(foobar2), field3 -> None))


  }

}
```

Comment: @José Silva, doesnt it answer your questions?